# How to make KVM guest stop showing both host and guest mouse cursors as it makes guest very hard to use?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, kvm-switch, virt-manager

I've created a CentOS 7 (KDE) VM on a Centos 7 KVM server without X or GUI, and there's only one guest on this server. I see two cursors in the virt-manager VM console: the host cursor and the guest cursor, and the moves of the guest cursor are restricted by the host cursor because it can't leave the screen boundaries. Kind of asynchronized cursors. The useful ["EvTouch USB Graphics Tablet" trick](https://superuser.com/questions/1160043/two-mouse-cursors-when-using-virt-manager) fixed this issue for any VM hosted on other servers but not on this one.

Anyway my tests makes more questions rise than giving a way :

1. I'm the only guy here with a Linux workstation in addition to my Windows one. So if I connect directly the virt-manager of my Linux Workstation to the KVM server with ssh key, and if I open the VM console, there's **only one** mouse cursor.
2. On Windows, if I try to connect directly with ssh to the KVM server with MobaXterm, then to start virt-manager from there, I have **two** unusable mouse cursors.
3. Best of all, if I connect my Windows PC to my Linux workstation with ssh and start its virt-manager, I also get **two** mouse cursors (seems really illogical to me as it worked fine when physically in front of the Linux workstation)

I even can't determine if the issue is server's side, guest's side or even Windows PC's side. Knowing that Windows PCs here have no problem with other CentOS VMs on similar KVM servers (similar = same OS version, virt-manager version and config).

Could you please help me to search in the right direction?

Comment: Have you installed Guest Extensions / Tools in the KVM Guest?  You normally need to do this in (say) VMware Workstation for the mouse to work correctly (guest or host but not both).   https://askubuntu.com/questions/858649/how-can-i-copypaste-from-the-host-to-a-kvm-guest

Comment: Thanks @John , but it's a KVM virtual machine as described in title, not a VMWare VM.

Comment: I know it is not VMware but the article should be helpful.  Ask KVM support about "tools" for it.

Comment: You're right, spice-vdagent exists in CentOS repository too. The weird thing is that we've never needed such a guest tool to fix it in tens of other CentOS VMs. But of course I will try. Thanks for your help. Will tell you how it works tomorrow (it's late night here).
Will also check virt-manager versions, and also screen resolution as seen [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/mouse-cursor-in-kvm-guest-4175575243/).

Comment: Hi @John, sorry but devs had some issues to resolve with their app and needed to use this machine today in TTY. Will let you know as soon as I can test.

Comment: Finally, it did the trick : installing spice-vdagent on guest VM and in the VM config on KVM server I set "spice vmc" and "unix" (org.qemu.guest-agent.0) modules to "connected" through virsh edit commands. Thanks a lot for your help @John. Could you please write your advice as an answer so I could vote for it as a solution?